# Prove a limit by checking epsilon,delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define P:[$\frac14$,$2$] $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb R$ By P(x)= $\left(\frac{cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt x}\right)$  Prove that $\lim_{x\to 1}$ P(x) = $\left(-1\right)$  by checking the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of function

Here is my prove:

$\vert P(x)+1\vert$< $\epsilon$

$\vert P(x)+1\vert$= $\vert(\frac{cos(\pi x)}{\sqrt x}) +1\vert$ $\le$ $\vert$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+1$ $\vert$ $\le$ 2($\sqrt x +1$)<$\epsilon$

$\vert$x-1$\vert< $$(\frac{\epsilon}{2}-1)$$^2$

$\forall$$\epsilon$>0, let $\delta$= $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}-1)$$^2$-$\left (1\right)$ , then $\forall$x$\in$[$\frac14$,$2$],

$\vert$x-1$\vert$<$\delta$ = $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}-1)$$^2$-$\left (1\right)$ implies

$\vert P(x)+1\vert$ $\le$ $\vert$ $\left(2(\sqrt x-1)\right)$ $\vert$<$\epsilon$

it is this proof strong enough? Any mistake i made? 
Thankyou for reply

Comment: We can not say cos p x is 1.( p is pie.)

Comment: it should be -1 ?

Comment: Sorry. I took your proof wrongly.@pasu2601. I thought you had put cospx=1.

Comment: I do not find anything wrong in this proof. Only you should have written |x-1|<|(e/2-1)^2-1|. ( e is epsilon). I think thats a silly mistake.